# Combinations - How to calculate average # of items in a subset, with a given number of items randomly picked out of a set?

Tags: combinatorics

If I randomly pick $k$ elements form a set $A$ of $n$ elements ($\binom{n}{k}$ combinations).
Assume the random distribution is totally even.

I now examine a given subset $B$ of $m$ elements from set $A$.
How can I calculate the average number $r$ of elements, randomly picked from $A$ that belong to $B$?

My stab at my own answer (with some help) is to first find the probability of finding $i$ elements ($i$ ranging from $0$ to $k$) in $B$ that were chosen in $A$: $P(i) = {\binom{m}{i} \times \binom{n-m}{k-i}\over{\binom{n}{k}}}$.

Then $r = \sum_{i=0}^k{i*P(i)}$.

I know this is wrong but I can't say why.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any difficult combinatorics here. Suppose instead of combinations you work with numbered selections (injective maps $\{1,\ldots,k\}\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$, also abusively called permutations); this will not alter the average number of elements that fall within $B$. But each element of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ now obviously has an expectation of $m/n$ of falling inside the set $B$. The assignments of elements are not independent, but expectation is linear so you can add up nonetheless: the expectation for the total number of elements falling inside$~B$ is $mk/n$. That is precisely the average value you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

We describe a quick way to find the expectation.  (Your expression, after the modification, is correct.)

Let our given subset $B$ be $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m\}$. Let $X_i=1$ if $b_i$ is picked among the $k$ elements, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the amount $Y$ of overlap between the random set and $B$ is given by $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_m$. Thus by the linearity of expectation, 
$$E(Y)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_m).$$
The probability that $b_i$ is in our chosen set is $\frac{k}{n}$. Thus $E(X_i)=\frac{k}{n}$, and $E(Y)=\frac{mk}{n}$.

**Remark:** We give a quick justification of your method. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to pick $k$ elements. Now we find the number of ways to do it so there are $i$ from $B$ and therefore $k-i$ from the rest of $A$. This can be done in $\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{k-i}$ ways. So the required probability $P(i)$ is
 given by
$$P(i)=\frac{\binom{m}{i}\binom{n-m}{k-i}}{\binom{n}{k}}.$$
Now use the formula for expectation, as you did, to obtain an expression for the answer. We do indeed sum from $i=0$ to $k$, with the understanding that $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $0\le a\lt b$.

With some work, the expression $\sum{i=0}^k iP(i)$ can be simplified to give the simple answer $\frac{mk}{n}$ of the answer above.

Comment: I don't follow the computation of E. Taking an example: n=20, m=10, k=5, yields E(Y)=2.5, which means the probability is greater than 1!? There is something I don't get here.

Comment: You calculated $E(Y)$. The random variable $Y$ is the amount of overlap between the given set $B$ and the random $k$-element set chosen. That overlap could be anything from $0$ to $5$. That the average amount of overlap is in this case $2.5$ is reasonable, since $B$ is half of the set $A$.

Comment: The problem I have with P(i) is that this seems to compare probabilities of counting any i from m by any (k-i) from (n-m) over any k from n. But does not consider that the i and k-i are the same as the k elements, so my figures are way down.

Comment: But the E(Y) and P(i) methods amount to very different results. So something is amiss and I think (maybe incorrectly) that both answers are wrong. Some tweaks needed, my brain is dead (these maths are 25 years away from me).

Comment: It is just like finding the number of hands of $5$ cards that have exactly $2$ hearts. We would get $\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}$.

Comment: The sum $\sum iP(i)$, if you compute carefully, will give exactly the same answer as the number given in the main answer. Think concretely, in terms of a poker hand of $5$, or a bridge hand of $13$, where $B$ is the set of hearts. Then the two expressions (one neat, one messy) each give the expected number of hearts in a random hand. You will see that the answer of the main post makes intuitive sense.

Comment: I would have loved to award both you and Marc the right answer, but I'm only allowed one. Marc's way to explain it made more sense to me. Thanks for your help.